# How to stop form from popping up

Tags: c#

I have a program where I am taking data from one form to the next, so it displays the same data on each form. Though when I try to Close the form or Hide it, one of the other forms that relayed the information from form 2 to form 3 keep showing up when I try to close form 3 and move to form 4. How do I close form 2 so that it doesn't come up anymore?

Here is my current code from form 2 that relays over to form 3:
I set this at the below the initializing component to read in the data from form 1

```
public string Username { get; set; }
public string MSG { get; set; }
```

Then I read in the values in the form2 load

```
label4.Text = Username;
label5.Text = MSG;
```

Then I try to relay the information to form 3 in a timer that is enabled for only 3 seconds:

```
using (var f = new form3())
{
     try
     {
         f.Username = label4.Text;
         f.MSG = label5.Text;
         f.ShowDialog();
     }
     catch
     {
         Application.Exit();
     }
     this.Close();
}
```

And then on form3 I try to use a button to go to form 4 and form 2 shows up again...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     form4.Show();
     this.Close();   
}
```

How do I stop this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
form4.Show();
```

To this:

```
form4.ShowDialog();
```

You're showing Form4 nonmodal, so `this.Close()` is immediately executed and Form3 closes. Form4 is still open but probably just drops to the background and Form2 comes back up to the front.

Comment: But when I do that and form2 stops popping up, I cannot execute the button on form4 properly like I can when I used form4.Show

Comment: I fixed it, Thanks. I needed to keep everything in modal format.